# How in dart, expose globaly an enum?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
enum Category{ restaurant, pizzera, fast_food, other }

class XXX ...
```

How to acess XXX.Category statically from other classes?

Many thanks for your time ;-)

Comment: You can make a new file, name it 'global_var.dart' maybe, then write enum Category{ restaurant, pizzera, fast_food, other }. You can access it globally.

Comment: What do you mean by _statically_

Answer (score 7):

There's no way to expose a file, class, enum, or otherwise to the global Dart context in such a way that all other files will *automatically* have access to it. You can create it as a global resource and then explicitly import it in other files that need it.

(myEnum.dart)

```dart
enum MyEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
}
```

(main.dart)

```dart
import 'relative/path/to/file/myEnum.dart'; // Load the contents of myEnum.dart into this file's scope

void main() {
  var e = MyEnum.value1;
  // Do whatever else you want with MyEnum
}
```

---

After rereading the question, it appears as though what you actually want is to declare the enum as a member of a static class, i.e. so you could refer to it using the syntax `ClassName.EnumName.value`. Sadly, nesting types is not supported in Dart. (You can't declare a class or enum within another class.)

You could use a workaround which would give the same syntactic result, though I would like to go on record as saying this is not recommended and is definitely in the territory of making things more complicated than they need to be.

(foo.dart)

```dart
enum _MyEnum {
  value1,
  value2,
  value3,
  value4,
}

class _MyEnumContainer {
  _MyEnum get value1 => _MyEnum.value1;
  _MyEnum get value2 => _MyEnum.value2;
  _MyEnum get value3 => _MyEnum.value3;
  _MyEnum get value4 => _MyEnum.value4;
}

class Foo {
  static _myEnumContainerInstance = _MyEnumContainer();
  static _MyEnumContainer get MyEnum => _myEnumContainerInstance;
}
```

(main.dart)

```dart
import 'foo.dart';

void main() {
  var e = Foo.MyEnum.value1;
}
```

---

Alternatively (and more recommended), you could also just import the file from the first example with a label. Granted this would purely be a cosmetic option and there would be no way to enforce this, but syntactically it achieves what you want.

```dart
import 'myEnum.dart' as Foo;

void main() {
  var e = Foo.MyEnum.value1;
}
```

Comment: Can assign values to enum elements in dart like enum day { MON(1), TUE(2),....} ??

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy That's a highly requested feature and may appear in the language someday, but right now, no, you can't assign arbitrary values to enums. You would instead have to use class constants for that.

Comment: For future readers, the above requested feature (referred to as "enhanced enums") is now available [as of Dart 2.17](https://dart.dev/language/enum).